# No container is selectable when creating Wolfram notebook in Wolfram Workbench

Tags: notebooks, workbench

I wanted to create a Wolfram notebook using Wolfram workbench and I must select a container in the first step but nothing is shown to select. I was wondering if anyone can explain what is a container here and how can I create a notebook in Wolfram Workbench.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the workspace is setup correctly for the Workbench.

File->New project, Choose Mathematica Project

Choose a Basic project (Or Application Project) Give it a name. This name will show up as the name of the container later. I have named it "test" inside the workspace\Base folder.

[image]

After the folder structure is in place, right click on `test` folder, choose New Source file or Notebook:

[image]